# UIScrollView contentOffset changes when its width constraint is changed

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a `UIScrollView` which has its width set by a constraint. I modify this constraint's constant as the view changes (in this example, when the interface orientation changes).

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    self.scrollViewWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.width;
}
```

Unfortunately, when this value changes I notice that the scroll view's content offset also changes (to a value I can't notice a pattern to). If the constant never changes, there are no irregularities.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Isn't that to be expected? If the content of your view is adjusted to fit a larger/small width, then the content offset should adjust so that the same content is shown on the screen. If the content offset didn't change, and your view is displaying a UITextView for example, the visible text would jump to a different position.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set constraints to scrollview, now if you change it's width then other constraints will also affect and try to satisfy. for example view have constraint with distance 5 from every side and if you increase width by 10 then leading and trailing  constrain get conflicts so, if you give width constraint then don't give leading and trailing both and same for height. So, in scrollview if you try to change with then it is possible that it's change it's position to satisfy other constraints. that's why content offset is changed to adjust likewise.

second thing,

You should not set fix height or width directly to scrollview. because it's scroll according to it's content's size. you should set top,bottom, leading,trailing to scrollview and give fix height or length to it's content view with horizontal or vertical center in container respactively according to requirement.

hope this will help :)